# apa6 package: heading line exceeds textwidth

Tags: header-footer, margins, apa6

I'm using the apa6 package with the document mode "doc". Now I ran into some problems with the heading line. On even pages the heading line exceeds the textwidth on the left hand side and on odd pages on the right hand side.

**Even page:**
[image: even]

**Odd page:**
[image: Odd page]
**Example Code:**

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\ifapamodeman{\setlength{\textwidth}{5.76772in}%
\setlength{\textheight}{9.19291in}}{}

\title{Sample APA-Style Document Using the \textsf{apa6} Package}
\author{Brian D. Beitzel}
\affiliation{SUNY Oneonta}
\leftheader{Beitzel}
\abstract{This is the abstract}
\keywords{APA style, demonstration}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Text long enough to fill several pages...
\end{document}
```

I guess it is a bug in this otherwise excellent apa6 package. Is there a quick (and dirty) way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say

```
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
```

just before `\begin{document}`